# View Polymorphism in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, polymorphism

What is the correct way to do view polymorphism in iOS? For example, I have custom table view cells that need to contain either a custom BarChartView or LineChartView. I decide at run time whether the table view cell will hold a line or bar chart. Ideally, I want to only create one xib file for the table view cell that layouts the bar/line chart view with other things (like labels for chart title, etc), and I can decide at run time whether the view that holds the chart is going to become a BarChartView or LineChartView. Is it possible to set the morphing view in the xib file in Interface Builder to be one of the superclasses, for example UIView, and then later programmatically decide which subclass it should become? If so, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Make two view in custom cell xib file for BarChartView or LineChartView.(Both in single xib only)

Step 2.Write conditions in  cellFoRowAtIndexPath to  get  either BarChartView or LineChartView view to Show.

Note:- Now,there might be condition ,weather to show/hide tableview ,depends on you.
But once tableview need to be displayed, use Step 1 & 2 to dynamic view loading.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but it doesn't seem like a very clean solution. If I'm understanding you correctly, doing this would mean I would be layering views on top of each other in the xib file, and if I were to later expand the view to support even more chart types, it would become difficult to work with.

Comment: yaah,To avoid layering of multiple view ,  just create different view's inside custom cell xib for each barCart, and   use addSubview's (To add view in cell contentView)  in cellForRow with conditions!!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe have a custom view inside contentView of your cell and just add barChartView or lineChartView to that view. So, even If you need to support more Chart types that'll be doable